# Magento search extremely slow. Profiler output

Tags: magento2, profiler

I have magento 2.4.5 and my own dedicated server with elastic search installed.
my catalogue page takes forever to load (16 sec). I have 18K products.

Magento profiler shows me:

```
TEMPLATE:/var/www/magento2/app/design/frontend/mytheme/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml.  with a 14.405653s time

  ·  EAV:load_collection    0.679354    
  ·  load_entities  0.571876    
  ·  set_orig_data  0.010517    
  ·  after_load 0.096795
```

There is nothing in mysql slowlog, I reindexed everything again, I have varnish installed.

What I am missing and what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Run these Command it helps to reduce time

```
bin/magento config:set dev/template/minify_html 1 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 1 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 1 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 1 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 1 &&\
bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work besides changing my layout. It is really the search that gives me this long times. Must be something with the template.